# C# code to wait until webpage finishes loading

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, load, html

I can not for the life of me figure out how to get my C# code to wait until the webpage finishes loading.  I can't get the ie.documentcompleted or ie.documentcomplete even close to working.  In fact even though I'm referencing the system.windows.forms assembly, I can't get VS2012 to give me documentcompleted as a dropdown option.  Please help.

Thanks

```
public static string getTheBlockArray()
        {
            SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
            string id = "resultsTable";
            object Empty = 0;
            object URL = "http://www.cmegroup.com/clearing/trading-practices/block-data.html#contractTypes=FUT,OPT,SPD&exchanges=XCME&assetclass=assetClassId=1,6";
            IE.Navigate2(ref URL, ref Empty, ref Empty, ref Empty, ref Empty);

            // Some code here to wait until the webpage loads

            object theRange = IE.Document.getelementbyID(id).innertext;
            string blockString = theRange.ToString();
            IE.Quit();
            return blockString;
        }
```

Comment: Since you're using winforms, can't you use the `WebBrowser` control and its `DocumentCompleted` event?

Comment: This is an old question, but the InternetExplorer object has a DocumentComplete event. Just add `ie.DocumentComplete += ie_DocumentComplete;` and do the getelementbyID and such in the event handler. You might need to delay the `IE.Quit();` until you have the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of resultsTable element filled by a javascript code via an async request. So you shouldn't process the DOM, instead you have to directly query the data, as the javascript does. This code below could be a good starting point.

```
  class Program
  {
    private static readonly string url = "http://www.cmegroup.com/clearing/trading-practices/CmeWS/mvc/xsltTransformer.do?xlstDoc=/XSLT/md/blocks-records.xsl&url=/da/BlockTradeQuotes/V1/Block/BlockTrades?exchange={0}&foi={1}&{2}&tradeDate={3}&sortCol={4}&sortBy={5}&_=1372913232800";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Exchange exchange = Exchange.XCME;
      ContractType contractType = ContractType.FUT | ContractType.OPT | ContractType.SPD;
      string assetClass = "assetClassId=0"; // See asset_class dropdown options in HTML source for valid values
      DateTime tradeDate = new DateTime(2013, 7, 3);
      string sortCol = "time"; // Column to sort
      SortOrder sortOrder = SortOrder.desc;

      string xml = QueryData(exchange, contractType, assetClass, tradeDate, sortCol, sortOrder);
      Console.WriteLine(xml);
    }

    private static string QueryData(Exchange exchange, ContractType contractType, string assetClass, DateTime tradeDate, string sortCol, SortOrder sortOrder)
    {
      string exc = GetEnumString(exchange);
      string ct = GetEnumString(contractType);
      string td = tradeDate.ToString("MMddyyyy");
      string query = string.Format(url, exc, ct, assetClass, td, sortCol, sortOrder.ToString());

      WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(query);
      request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
      using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
      {
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
          using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
          {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
          }
        }
      }
    }

    private static string GetEnumString(Enum item)
    {
      return item.ToString().Replace(" ", "");
    }
  }

  [Flags]
  enum Exchange
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// CBOT.
    /// </summary>
    XCBT = 1,

    /// <summary>
    /// CME.
    /// </summary>
    XCME = 2,

    /// <summary>
    /// COMEX.
    /// </summary>
    XCEC = 4,

    /// <summary>
    /// DME.
    /// </summary>
    DUMX = 8,

    /// <summary>
    /// NYMEX.
    /// </summary>
    XNYM = 16
  }

  [Flags]
  enum ContractType
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Futures.
    /// </summary>
    FUT = 1,

    /// <summary>
    /// Options.
    /// </summary>
    OPT = 2,

    /// <summary>
    /// Spreads.
    /// </summary>
    SPD = 4
  }

  enum SortOrder
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Ascending.
    /// </summary>
    asc,

    /// <summary>
    /// Descending.
    /// </summary>
    desc
  }
```

The result is in the xml variable ([see](http://kepfeltoltes.hu/130705/Result_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png)).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while(IE.Busy)
{
    //You might want to sleep or count or something.
    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: while(IE.Busy){Application.DoEvents()} Doesn't wait until the page is loaded. Thanks though.

Comment: I think you are confusing the page loading, with the page completing all of it's async requests.  The page is done loading before the table of stocks is rendered.  If you are expecting the table to be full when the page is loaded, you are out of luck.  You can wait until the page is done loading, and then wait another 2 or 3 seconds, but obviously that's not fool proof.

Comment: FWIW, with a tool like Selenium you could wait for a particular dom element to be present.

Comment: If it's some AJAX call, why not just have your app do *that* call instead?

Answer (score 0):

does not IE.Completed works?

if iy works, you could try do something like that:

```
IE.completed += (s, e) => {
  // your code
```

};